# c# form load order issue

Tags: c#, winforms

Having a bit of a strange issue trying to change my form load order.

I believe to change the load order, I simply need to go to the Program.cs file and change this line:

`Application.Run(new AdminPage());` - This is what it is currently set too:

to this -`Application.Run(new AdminLogin());`

This is giving me the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'AdminLogin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is a screenshot to show the layout of my project. I cant see what Im doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: What is the namespace of AdminLogin and what is the namespace of AdminPage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the AdminLogin class in the same namespace as Program? If not, use `using` statement to use that namespace.

Comment: I see the issue, I accidently created the form in my 'Pics' folder so the name space is 'adminPanel.pics' instead of 'adminPanel'. Is there an easy way to change the change namespace name?

Comment: Yes, simply change the `namespace adminPanel.pics` definition to `namespace adminPanel` at the top of AdminLogin.cs file

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment the answer of Axarydax so i'll answer here.

You can simply erase the ".pics" of your namespace in AdminLogin so that it become adminPanel instead of adminPanel.pics